# finding a constant with log and a cubic polynomial to find upper bounding function

Tags: inequality, polynomials, logarithms

I have this function $163.6718+48.7542n-1.376957n^2+0.01518444n^3$. And want to find the big-O constant as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249151/big-o-notation-finding-c-and-n0) for n³. Except for n³, I have nlog(n) as an upper-bounding function.

The function does not have to hold true for n>50

The (in)equation would look like

$163.6718+48.7542n-1.376957n^2+0.01518444n^3 <= c*nlog(n)$

I do not know how to get divide by log(n) or if it is even possible. Anyway, I am trying to find $c$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such $c$ exist, let $n=1$,

Then the left hand side is positive but the right hand side is $0$.

Suppose you want to make the statement to be true for $n \in \{2, \ldots, 50\}$.

Let $f(n)$ be your cubic polynomial, you just have to evaluate

$\frac{f(n)}{n \log(n)}$ for these $49$ values and pick the maximum value.

Comment: I wanted to do $g(x) = nlog(n/2)+250$, such that $g(x) > f(x)$ so what you said was very helpful I ended up with $(-86+48.7542x-1.376957x^2+0.01518444x^3)/( x*log(x/2))$ Except then $n<3$ would result in very odd results. Luckily, I wanted g(x)>f(x) for all x >= 5 giving me a $c$ of $63$. http://puu.sh/zIQ6P/03431aa846.png

Comment: By the way. The way I found the 63 was by plotting the $\frac{f(n)}{n \log(n)}$ and reading off the max value. Is this a proper way of finding the max?

Comment: the numbers are finite, less than $50$ which is very small for those who know programming. so I would just code it out or plot and read off the value. Alternatively, you can try to consider the continuous versions, find stationary point and solve for it, not sure how easy it is and whether it's worth it.